# Passing Value of DataGridView from One form to a Class

Tags: c#, datagridview, parameter-passing

I am having difficulties in passing the values of a DataGridView to a class. I want to read all contents of the datagridview of a form using a separate class. I tried the following (suppose dgv1 is an existing dataGridView with contents):

```
public void buttonClick()
{
    SeparateClass separateClass = new SeparateClass();
    separateClass.getDataGridViewDetails(dgv1);
}
```

and the following code receives dgv1 in a separate class:

```
public void getDataGridViewDetails(DataGridView dgv1)
{
     string celValue = dgv1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

but returns a null value, which means I have failed to pass the value of the existing DataGridView to another class. Can you tell me what is the correct code to pass the value of a DataGridView to another class. Thanks a lot. . .

Comment: Firstly you will have to make sure that dgv1 has the modifier set to public. If the class is in another namespace you will probably have to import the form from the other namespace as well.

Comment: did you try change `Modifiers` propertie to `public`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this I would access the DataGridView from my Class using the following..

**In your form you would have..**

```
public void buttonClick()
{
   SeparateClass separateClass = new SeparateClass();
   seperateClass.formObj = this;
   seperateClass.getDataGridViewDetails();
}
```

**In your class you would have..**

```
public Form1 formObj;

public void getDataGridViewDetails()
{
   string celValue = formObj.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments above, you would need to set the DataGridView Modifier to `Public`